# Sequelize set associated value

Tags: node.js, associations, sequelize.js

I have two models, **Employee**s and **Office**s. Every Employee belongs to one Office, and an Office has many Employees.

I am having difficulty figuring out how to update an Employee's office using Sequelize.

The **Employee** model is as follows:

```
let Employee = sequelize.define("Employee", {
    id: {
        field: 'id',
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: false
   },
   name: {
        field: 'name',
        type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
        allowNull: false
   }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false,
    deletedAt: false
})

Employee.associate = models => {
    Employee.belongsTo(models.Office, {
        foreignKey: 'id'
    })
}
```

The **Office** model is as follows:

```
let Office = sequelize.define("Office", {
    id: {
        field: 'id',
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
   },
   name: {
        field: 'name',
        type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
        allowNull: false
   }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'Lkup_Office',
    timestamps: false,
    deletedAt: false
})
Office.associate = models => {
    Office.hasMany( models.Employee, {
        foreignKey: 'id'
    })
}
```

In the database I have the following Employee:

```
{
    "id": "2",
    "name" : "John",
    "office": {
        "id": 2,
        "name" : "Seattle"
    }
}
```

... and the following Offices:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name" : "Chicago"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name" : "Seattle"
    }
]
```

I want to change the ID of Employee(1)'s office from `2` (`'Seattle'`) to `1` (`'Chicago'`); the problem is that with the following query

```
// PUT /2/office/1

router.put('/:employeeId/office/:officeId', (req, res) => {
    models.Employee.findOne({
        where:{id:req.params.employeeId},
        include:[{model:models.Office}]
    }).then( employee => {

        models.Office.findOne({
            where:{id:req.params.officeId},
            include:[{model:models.Employee}]
        }).then( office => {

            employee.setOffice( office ).then( result => {
                res.send( result )
            })

        })
    })
})
```

... my Employee's office is not updated:

```
{
    "id": "2",
    "name" : "John"
    "office": {
        "id": 2
        "name" : "Seattle"
    }
}
```

It doesn't, in fact, do anything at all: no errors, the DB isn't changed. I have a suspicion that there's something I'm not doing correctly, but Sequelize isn't throwing any errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.put('/:employeeId/office/:officeId', (req, res) => {

    /*In this first part, I just separated the two queries into two
      separate variables*/

    let employeeInfo = models.Employee.findOne({
        where: {
            id: req.params.employeeId
        },
        include: [{
            model: models.Office
        }]
    });

    let officeInfo = models.Office.findOne({
        where: {
            id: req.params.officeId
        },
        include: [{
            model: models.Employee
        }]
    });

    /*In this next part, we have to use Promise.all, which comes with 
      bluebird, which is already a part of Sequelize.js. How this next
      part is executed will depend on how you have your Sequelize.js code
      structured in your application. This may require some trial and error*/

    models.sequelize.Promise.all([employeeInfo, officeInfo]).then(([Employee, Office])=> {
        return Employee.setOffice(Office);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```